# In Canada, are options available to subsidize conversion of a house into an energy efficient house?

Tags: canada, rebate, subsidy

I'm looking to convert a house into a more energy efficient version of it; what options or services can I access, that are specifically designed to help with the financing of the conversion? Has anyone gone through this process, and can give pointers as to which choices are likely to be cost efficient?

The house is located near Toronto, Canada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be more, but a good starting point would be the [ecoENERGY Retrofit Grants and Incentives](http://oee.nrcan.gc.ca/corporate/retrofit-summary.cfm).

> Natural Resources Canada's ecoENERGY Retrofit program provides financial support to implement energy-saving projects. There are different application processes for homes, commercial and institutional buildings and industrial facilities. Together we can reduce energy-related greenhouse gases and air pollution, leading to a cleaner environment for Canada.

Also, there was a temporary home renovation tax credit about a year back, but that no longer exists and nothing has replaced it yet.